# CentOS 6 Cron Logging Without Postfix

Tags: centos, cron, postfix

On a CentOS environment I am setting up, I have no need for email of any kind. I would like to simply disable postfix entirely, however this also disables logging from cron which I do need to have.

Is there, first, a method by which I can get cron logging to work without postfix, or second, limit postfix functionality such that only enough to support cron logging is enabled?

I've no experience with postfix, so I'm shooting in the dark here.

EDIT: I should specify, I need the cron job output (stdout,stderr) in a log file, not just the jobs that were run.

Comment: Which cron jobs are getting sent to you via email? I'd modify the cron job's themselves so that they properly write their logs out instead. The feature that cron sends emails with the results is a catchall for poorly written jobs that do not deal with their own output. You can also do this as described in this AU Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500749/cron-job-not-running-postfix-sendmail-error.

Comment: I was really hoping to not have to modify the scripts or the crontabs, as I know I can add logging to the scripts or output redirection from the jobs in the crontab.

I figured that since cron was logging output already, and able to mail it locally, that I could get the same functionality through syslog. However, I have not been able to get that to actually work.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want remove your system MTA?
This only give you problems, many apps require MTA for right working.

I recomend you don't do that.
In addition, the charge on the system is trivial if it don't have activity.

Regards,